# PySide: QTreeView to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pyside, qtreeview

I need help to build a hierarchical nested dict from a QTreeView structure to get something like this:

```
 {"A": {"B": {"H": {}, "I": {"M": {}, "N": {}}}, "D": {}, "E": {}, "F": {}, "G": {"L": {}}, "C": {"J": {}, "K": {}}}}

{
    "A": {
        "B": {
            "H": {}, 
            "I": {
                "M": {}, 
                "N": {}
             }
        }, 
        "D": {}, 
        "E": {}, 
        "F": {}, 
        "G": {
            "L": {}
        }, 
        "C": {
            "J": {}, 
            "K": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I am not using columns in this case and the QTreeView represents a directory structure (i actually extracted it from a dict like tho one above and just want to recreate the dict after modifying the Tree)

I already have some thing like this:

```
def to_dict(self, _structure={}, _parent=''):
    sublist[self.name()] = self._children

    for child in self._children:
        _structure[self.name()] = sublist
        child.to_dict(_structure, self.name())
```

Obviously self._children is a list so it wont work

EDIT: I think i might need something like this:

```
def to_dict(self, _structure={}, _parent=''):

    sublist = {self.name(): {}}

    for child in self._children:
        if _parent == '':
            _structure = sublist
        else:
            _structure[_parent].update(sublist)
        child.to_dict(_structure, self.name())

    return _structure
```

The Problem here is...i need to find the _parent key in the _structure dictionary and as far as i understand it will always be in the lowest level of the dict...do i really need to search the whole _structure dict averytime a want to add a new subdict to the given _parent or is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert the dictionary to a model then you have to iterate recursively on the dictionary, and according to the type of data insert it into the model. In the opposite case it is the same.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

def fill_model_from_json(parent, d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            child = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(k)) 
            parent.appendRow(child)
            fill_model_from_json(child, v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            fill_model_from_json(parent, v)
    else:
        parent.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(d)))

def fill_dict_from_model(parent_index, d):
    v = {}
    for i in range(model.rowCount(parent_index)):
        ix = model.index(i, 0, parent_index)
        fill_dict_from_model(ix, v)
    d[parent_index.data()] = v

def model_to_dict(model):
    d = dict()
    for i in range(model.rowCount()):
        ix = model.index(i, 0)
        fill_dict_from_model(ix, d)    
    return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    data =  {"A": {"B": {"H": {}, "I": {"M": {}, "N": {}}}, "D": {}, "E": {}, "F": {}, "G": {"L": {}}, "C": {"J": {}, "K": {}}}}
    fill_model_from_json(model.invisibleRootItem(), data)
    tree.setModel(model)
    tree.expandAll()
    tree.resize(360, 480)
    tree.show()
    d = model_to_dict(model)
    assert(d == data)
    print(d)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Ty for the answer. I think you missunderstood my question, though. I have a QTreeView with a working tree. What i need is to build a nested dict like shown from that Tree.