# Multi-Level QTreeView using dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pyqt5, qtreeview

I am trying to use dictionaries in a QTreeView to create a multi-level view, I found a post that works almost the same as how I want it, but I don't want the text showing on the 'value' column for every level/sublevel. And also remove the extra row under the items that has the value. Any tips on how I can implement this?

[PySide: QTreeView to nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743481/pyside-qtreeview-to-nested-dictionary)

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore,QtWidgets
import sys

class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        tree = {'RootLevel':{
                    "Level1": {"Level1_item1":14, "Level1_item2":12, "Level1_item3":3.55},
                    "Level2": {
                        "Level2_SubLevel1": {"Level2_SubLevel1_item1":3.52, "Level2_SubLevel1_item2":2.55, "Level2_SubLevel1_item3":13},
                        "Level2_SubLevel2": {"Level2_SubLevel2_item1":2, "Level2_SubLevel2_item2":4, "Level2_SubLevel2_item3":3.11}
                        },
                    "Level3": {"Level3_item1":12, "Level3_item2":13.55, "Level3_item3":122}}
        }

        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        root_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.tree.setModel(root_model)
        self.tree.model().setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Level','Values'])
        self.fill_model_from_json(root_model.invisibleRootItem(), tree)

    def fill_model_from_json(self,parent, d):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for k, v in d.items():
                child = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(k))
                value = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(v)) 
                parent.appendRow([child,value])
                self.fill_model_from_json(child, v)
        elif isinstance(d, list):
            for v in d.items():
                self.fill_model_from_json(parent, v)
        else:
            parent.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(d)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Desired Result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure is different so the other method does not work, in your case only the first column is filled except in the case that it is not a dictionary because in that case the second column is refilled:

```py
def fill_model_from_json(self, parent, d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key, value in d.items():
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(key))
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                parent.appendRow(it)
                self.fill_model_from_json(it, value)
            else:
                it2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                parent.appendRow([it, it2])
```

[image]