# Drill down QListWidget

Tags: pyqt5, qlistwidget

I can show a list of items in the QListWidget, and on click get the item selected. What I can't seem to figure out how to drill down the data (I don't want to use tree view).

So as an example, the first list could be list of TV Shows. Clicking a show shows list of Seasons. Clicking a season shows the list of episodes.

I can clear and add items back to the tree, but I want to retain the ability to go back to previous list.

Would hide the top list, create new list, and add a back item element clicking which deletes the top level and shows the previous list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of recreating the information of a QListWidget you can use a model with a tree-like structure with a QListView and change the rootIndex of the view:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

data = {
    "item1": {
        "item 1-1": ["item 1-1-1", "item 1-1-2", "item 1-1-3"],
        "item 1-2": ["item 1-2-1", "item 1-2-2", "item 1-2-3"],
        "item 1-3": ["item 1-3-1", "item 1-3-2", "item 1-3-3"],
    },
    "item2": {
        "item 2-1": ["item 2-1-1", "item 2-1-2", "item 2-1-3"],
        "item 2-2": ["item 2-2-1", "item 2-2-2", "item 2-2-3"],
        "item 2-3": ["item 2-3-1", "item 2-3-2", "item 2-3-3"],
    },
    "item3": {
        "item 3-1": ["item 3-1-1", "item 3-1-2", "item 3-1-3"],
        "item 3-2": ["item 3-2-1", "item 3-2-2", "item 3-2-3"],
        "item 3-3": ["item 3-3-1", "item 3-3-2", "item 3-3-3"],
    },
}

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747062
def fill_model_from_json(parent, d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            child = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(k))
            parent.appendRow(child)
            fill_model_from_json(child, v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            fill_model_from_json(parent, v)
    else:
        parent.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(d)))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.view = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Up")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.view)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.setEnabled(False)

        self.view.clicked.connect(self.handle_view_clicked)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handle_button_clicked)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.view.setModel(model)

        fill_model_from_json(model.invisibleRootItem(), data)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def handle_view_clicked(self, index):
        if self.view.model().hasChildren(index):
            self.view.setRootIndex(index)
        self.button.setEnabled(self.view.rootIndex().isValid())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_button_clicked(self):
        self.view.setRootIndex(self.view.rootIndex().parent())
        self.button.setEnabled(self.view.rootIndex().isValid())


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks this does give me the desired result (altough I didn't understand half the code, still new to PyQt5). Can I make this lazy loading? e.g clicking item3 calls an api which returns items3-1, items3-2....

Comment: @MavWolverine Can I make this lazy loading? Yes, you can do that, check the canFetchMore and fetchMore method of the QAbstractItemModel class.